# How to use DAO recordset AddNew updating on split databases with links

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

After creating a database, testing it, and confirming that all routines execute perfectly i run into problems with the DAO record set commands once i split the database and link the tables.  The following below is one (of many) DAO record "ADD NEW" commands that no longer function after the split.  Strangely, i found one workaround to this problem by deleting the linked table, and creating an identical local table in the front end where the record is then updated correctly but for my needs, this workaround will not be acceptable for there are too many tables which i need to contain in the back end database for security purposes.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblHoldingProjectDeepDive01", dbOpenTable)
rst.AddNew
rst!ID_Project_Sub_Phase = Me.IDProjSubPhase
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, `dbOpenTable` works with local tables but not with linked tables. For an updateable recordset involving linked tables use `dbOpenDynaset` instead. (For a read-only recordset you could use `dbOpenSnapshot`.)

Comment: You saved me again Gord. Thank you..  A question if you have a moment.  Given that I plan on splitting the majority of my databases and distributing front ends to the users, do you reccomend that i replace all my dbOpenTables commands with dbOpenDynaset ??   Is there any benefit going forward to using dbOpenTable?

Comment: @MarcheseIlChihuahua I would just go with `dbOpenDynaset`.

Comment: Thanks again Gord.  If you have a chance, would you be able to have a think about the other question I recently posted about why I am not able to take my split database and make an execute only file.  I have exausted all sources on this one and am finding nothing useful.